# How to display values in listBox() for multiple selection using Yii2

Tags: php, mysql, listbox, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am creating a blog using Yii2. I have basic DB structure having tables:
Posts
Categories
Posts_Categories

I am using Yii2 ActiveForm to create post creation form. There are input fields for Title (text field), Content (text area), Categories (list box for multiple category selection).

I am not able to populate listBox with db values.

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'Title')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'Content')->textarea(['rows' => 6]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'CategoryId')->listBox(\yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map(\backend\models\Category::find()->all(),'CategoryId','CategoryName',['multiple' => true])); ?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

It is throwing following error:

```
Unknown Property – yii\base\UnknownPropertyException

Getting unknown property: backend\models\Category::1
```

There is error in listbox line. Secondly, after populating the data in listbox, how can I handle data insertion with respect to posts and multiple categories relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have syntax error in listBox. so, complete end parenthesis `)` before `multiple` property.

Like as,

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'CategoryId')->listBox(\yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map(\backend\models\Category::find()->all(),'CategoryId','CategoryName'),['multiple' => true]); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

For the second part of your question on data insertion. You may need to traverse the array of the selected (posted) items in the list box. Here is an example that may be included in the `actionCreate()` or `actionUpdate()` functions of your controller file (I am assuming `PostController.php`):

```
$selectedList = $_POST['model_name']['CategoryId'];
if(isset($selectedList)) {
    foreach($selectedList as $value){
        $pcmodel = new Post_Categories(); //assumption on model name
        //do neccessary check here
        $pcmodel->post_id = $postmodel->id;
        //assumption that value is being stored
        $pcmodel->category_id = $value; 
        $pcmodel->save(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not ideal but yeah also doesn't work with just $modelForm->load(Yii::$app->request->post())

Why does Yii not automatically populate a model's member array from a listBox (POSTed) input?